# counting duplicates using map c++

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

I'm trying to count duplicates using map and I'm using vector of struct.

I keep having error at this part:

```
void display(const std::map<ChildInfo, unsigned int>& counts) {
    for (auto count = counts.begin(); count != counts.end(); ++count) {
        std::cout << "Value " << count->first << " has count " << count->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the error is about << operand but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: what does `count->first` refer to ? Is it a `ChildInfo` object. If yes, then how are you supposed to print is without overloading the `<< operator`

Comment: Cut this down to a [mcve] and you'll see it has absolutely nothing to do with counting duplicates or maps.

Comment: @PRP why do I need to overload the << operator??

Comment: @iksemyonov answer explains what I told in the comments. See that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an overload of the `operator<<()` for the `ChildInfo` struct:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const ChildInfo& ci) {
    str << "id " <<  ci.id << " gram " << ci.gram << "\n";
    return str;
}
```

When the compiler encounters `std::cout << count->first`, then `operator<<(std::ostream,&, ChildInfo&)` is called, that's now C++ operators work. (Precisely, this code equivalents to `operator<<(std::cout, count->first)`) But there is no overload of the said operator for your `struct ChildInfo`. It's only defined for basic types and for standard library types, but as far as the latter goes, that was done by the library developers the same way as shown above. So, define it to fix the error.

See [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for reference.

Also *do get in the habit of specifying the exact error message* that you're getting. A programmer, or any engineer for that matter, *must* be precise, else it's not going to work, period.

Answer (score 0):

In the function display, you want to display `ChildInfo` elements (the `count->first` elements of the map, but you did not defined an operator << for this class.

A simple solution is to add something like

```
ostream& operator << (ostream & os, const ChildInfo& lhs) 
{ 
    os << lhs.id; 
    return os; 
}
```

Of course, you can change the content to be displayed.